# Negative milliseconds in program

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
      //Global variables
bool pause;

        TextView ClickToStart;
        TextView ClickAsSoonAsPossible;
        TextView Tries;
        TextView TriesCount;
        TextView AverageMs;
        TextView AverageMsCount;
        Button ScreenClickButton;
        System.Timers.Timer timer1;
        Color currentColor = Color.White;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        DateTime startTime1;
        DateTime endTime1;
        int secondsToFormat;

        int ClicksCount = 0;



  private void Timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Timer", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        currentColor = Color.Green;
                        ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(currentColor);
                    });
                    timer1.Stop();
                    startTime1 = DateTime.Now;
                }


            private void ClickCount(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (currentColor == Color.White)
                {

                    currentColor = Color.Red;
                    ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(currentColor);
                    int seconds = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Seconds:" + seconds, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    timer1.Interval = seconds * 1000;
                    timer1.Start();

                }
                else if (currentColor == Color.Green)
                {
                    endTime1 = DateTime.Now;
                    ClicksCount++;

                    secondsToFormat =endTime1.Millisecond - startTime1.Millisecond;

     AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();

                   // if(secondsToFormat>=1000)
                 //   {
                 //       AverageMs.Text = ((endTime1 - startTime1).Milliseconds).ToString();
                 //   }

                    currentColor = Color.White;
                    ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(currentColor);
                }
                else if (currentColor == Color.Red)
                {

                    currentColor = Color.White;
                    ScreenClickButton.SetBackgroundColor(currentColor);
                }


                //Toast.MakeText(this, "You clicked me " + ClicksCount + "times", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if (ClicksCount == 1)

                    AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();
                TriesCount.Text = "1";

                if (ClicksCount == 2)
                {
                    secondsToFormat = secondsToFormat / 2;
                    AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();

                    TriesCount.Text = "2";

                }
                if (ClicksCount == 3)
                {
                    secondsToFormat = secondsToFormat / 3;
                    AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();
                    TriesCount.Text = "3";
                }
                if (ClicksCount == 4)
                {
                    secondsToFormat = secondsToFormat / 4;
                    AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();
                    TriesCount.Text = "4";

                }

                if (ClicksCount == 5)
                {
                    secondsToFormat = secondsToFormat / 5;
                    AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();
                    TriesCount.Text = "5";
                }


                if (Click`enter code here`sCount == 6)
                {
                    ClicksCount = 1;

                }



            }
```

Hello guys, I'm trying to do something like this on Android Xamarin : https://www.humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime/ . So after first click return of milliseconds is negative like -525 . After some clicks its getting highier till finally positive. Could someone explain why its negative? Timer elapsed is basically for green screen to pop up in random time.After its poped up my milisecond count is started. And when clicked on green button its finished. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: var elapsedMS = (endTime1 - startTime1).TotalMilliseconds;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
secondsToFormat = endTime1.Millisecond - startTime1.Millisecond;
```

The `Millisecond` property is "the millisecond within the second". So suppose we have:

```
startTime1 = 2018-06-02T18:52:30.750Z 
endTime1 = 2018-06-02T18:52:31.100Z
```

... that will give you a result of -650ms, because `startTime1.Millisecond` is 100, and `endTime1.Millisecond` is 750.

Ideally:

- Don't use `DateTime` at all for this: use a `Stopwatch` which you reset and start whenever you want to start timing, then use the `Elapsed` property to get a `TimeSpan` whenever you want to find out how much time has passed. Use the `TotalMilliseconds` property of that `TimeSpan` to find out how many milliseconds have elapsed. (Alternatively, use `Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds`.)
- If you *have* to keep using `DateTime`

  - Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`, so that if your user runs this over a time zone offset change boundary (e.g. for daylight saving time) you don't end up with weird results
  - Take the difference between the two values as a `TimeSpan`, e.g. `endTime1 - startTime1`, and then again use the `TotalMilliseconds` property

Comment: Can you please give me example of how to start timer with Stopwatch?

Comment: @Rectinho: You use `Stopwatch.StartNew`, which returns you a `Stopwatch` which has started.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting milliseconds in Elapsed Time. How to convert them to Int to be able to divide it, I want to get average TimeSpan.

Comment: Error which I'm getting right now is: 'cannot be applied to operands of type 'TimeSpan' and 'int'

Comment: @Rectinho: Without seeing your code, I can't tell what's wrong. I suggest you ask a new question with that code (and only the relevant code - most of the code presented in this question is irrelevant to demonstrating the problem).